# Bind value in Blazor application only if button is clicked

Tags: blazor

I am new to Blazor so I am not sure if this supported or I will have to use JS for it.

I have got an input field bound to a C# field in a Blazor application

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="@someField"/>
```

and a button:

```
< button type="button" @onclick="UpdateSomeField"/>
```

What I want to achieve is, only when the button is clicked the C# field `someField` should be updated with the value of the input field.

Any idea how this can bed done?

**UPDATE**

The UpdateSomeField Method should take value of the input field and update the Database and update the DOM with it (ex. in a table)

```
@code{
  private string someField;

  private void UpdateSomeField(){
    someField = //value of input field
    // Update Database
  } 
}
```

Comment: No offense, but you might want to go through a YouTube tutorial series, or try this: https://blazor-university.com/  This isn't the kind of question that someone who'd studied for more than an hour or two would be likely to ask.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973  Thank you for your advice, I have looked there for answers before posting this question, but haven't found anything helpful

Comment: Fine.  Show what you're doing in your `UpdateSomeField` method, and I'll be happy to correct it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "What I want to achieve is, only when the button is clicked the C# field someField should be updated with the value of the input field." You're typing the value into the input field, so it's already updated before the button is clicked. How could it possibly be otherwise? Or is there some other input field involved? Like, you're taking the value from one input field and updating another with it when the button is clicked?

Comment: @EricKing Correct the C# field "someField" could bind to other elements too, so when you enter a new value in the input field and click the button it should update all the other elements too.

Comment: You don't need a button click to do that. Binding the `someField` variable to the input will cause the variable to be updated automatically when the input changes, and any other UI elements bound to that field will also be updated. That's what databinding does. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for the details.

Comment: In other words, the default databinding will update the variable on the onchange event of the input, no need for a button click to do it. The button click event can be used to send the variable value to the server for saving in the database.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blazor+tutorials

Answer (score 1):

To (specifically ) answer your question, you can do this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="@_someField" />

<button type="button" @onclick="UpdateSomeField"/>

@code {

    private string _someField;

    private string someField;

    private void UpdateSomeField()
    {
        someField = _someField;
        // Update Database
    }
}
```

For your code to access the value in the `input`, it must be bound to a field in your component.  So if you don't want to set `someField` until you click on the button, you need an intermediate field to hold the input value.

[Polite] It seems to be a pretty silly way of doing it, but if that's what you want to do, it's your project.